# How to set JSON element tag into ListView?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I have this JSON file and I must put each value of tag "info" into a ListView with click to open the url value in a WebView. The ActionBar title is set with value of the "title" JSON tag.

```
{
"mobiledata": {
    "geoJson_1": "http://###.###.###",
    "geoJson_2": "",
    "info": [
        {
            "title": "Italia",
            "uri": "https://mysite.wordpress.com/i/"
        },
        {
            "title": "Il tempo",
            "uri": "https://mysite.wordpress.com/il/"
        },
        {
            "title": "Le info",
            "uri": "https://mysite.wordpress.com/la-terra/"
        },
        {
            "title": "Il rischio",
            "uri": "https://mysite.wordpress.com/italia/regioni-italiane/"
        },
        {
            "title": "Le Rubriche mensili",
            "uri": "https://mysite.wordpress.com/tag/rubricamensile/"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

How can I do this? Any help or examples?

Comment: Adapter accepts only collections. Convert json to a collection and pass it to adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Approach given in old answer is too verbose. Steps to improve:

1. Use Gson library, it's fast and compact. Add into your module-level build.gradle file:

   ```
   dependencies {
       // your dependencies: AppCompat, HTTP client etc
       compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
   }
   ```
2. Declare appropriate data structure:

   ```
   class InfoItem {
       String title;
       String uri;
   }
   ```
3. Parse data:

   ```
   JsonElement data = new JsonParser().parse(json);
   ```
4. Get mobiledata.info:

   ```
   JsonArray info = data
           .getAsJsonObject() // treat parsed data as map
           .getAsJsonObject("mobiledata") // get 'mobiledata' as map
           .getAsJsonArray("info"); // get 'info' as list
   ```
5. map parsed jsonObjects into POJOs

   ```
   List<InfoItem> items = new Gson()
           .fromJson(info, new TypeToken<List<InfoItem>>(){}.getType());
   ```
6. Use your own adapter. With `ViewHolder` pattern binding will look like this:

   ```
   InfoItem item = items.get(position);
   holder.title.setText(item.title);
   holder.uri.setText(item.uri);
   ```

P. S. You may cache this ugly TypeToken:

```
    private static final Type type = 
            new TypeToken<List<InfoItem>>(){}.getType();
```

Full code to test:

```
    public class SoJsonAnswer {

        private static final Type type = 
                new TypeToken<List<InfoItem>>(){}.getType();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String json = "{paste it here}";
            JsonElement data = new JsonParser().parse(json);

            JsonArray info = data
                    .getAsJsonObject() // treat parsed data as map
                    .getAsJsonObject("mobiledata") // get map
                    .getAsJsonArray("info"); // get list

            // map parsed jsonObjects into POJOs
            List<InfoItem> items = new Gson().fromJson(info, type);

            System.out.println(items);
        }

    }

    class InfoItem {
        String title;
        String uri;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "title=" + title + ", uri=" + uri;
        }
    }
```

## Original answer

1. Include a JSON library in your project.
   I use this: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list
2. Parse as object.

   ```
   String json = "{...}"; //Your JSON here
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); //Can cause ParseException
   JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json); //Can cause ClassCastException
   ```
3. Get inner data.

   ```
   JSONObject mobileData = (JSONObject) obj.get("mobiledata");
   JSONArray info = (JSONArray) mobileData.get("info");
   ```
4. Pack this data into an ArrayList. Just use `for` cycle, `get` your items and cast them to `String`.

   ```
   ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>(info.size());
   Map<String, Object> m;
   JSONObject current;
   for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
     m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     current = (JSONObject) info.get(i);

     m.put("title", (String) current.get("title"));
     m.put("url", (String) current.get("url"));
     data.add(m);
   }
   ```
5. Set `Adapter` for a `ListView`.

   ```
   String[] from = { "title", "url" };
   int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
   from, to);
   lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Hope it helps.
Code not tested.

Comment: An example of hashMap for cast any url tag into a string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to vote for [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) on this one.

See this code sample:

```
public class MyFunClassName {
    // GSON matches class names with json keys... but you can get around that with the @SerializedName annotation... see below
    public MobileData mobileData;

    public class MobileData {
        @SerializedName("geoJson_1") // grabs the correct json key so you can name object whatever you want
        public String someUrl;

        @SerializedName("geoJson_2")
        public String someString;

        public List<Info> info;

        public class Info {
            public String title;
            public String uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the class where you're getting the json response:

```
// This uses gson to grab your json response
// string is required, so just use toString() - Put in object class name so gson knows where to parse the info
MyFunClassName myFunObject = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(), MyFunClassName.class);

// Now you can just use your new fun object
String chosenUri = myFunObject.mobileData.info.get(1).uri;
```